# Independent Infinite Family of Collections of Events

Tags: probability

An infinite family of collections $\{\mathcal{A}_{i}\}_{i \in I}$ is defined to be independent if every finite subfamily is independent. From this it follows that if $\{\mathcal{A}_{n}\}_{n \geq 1}$ is independent and $A_{n} \in \mathcal{A}_{n}$ for all $n \geq 1$ then

$P(\bigcap^{\infty}_{n=1}A_{n})=\Pi^{\infty}_{n=1}P(A_{n})$

I'm struggling to see the link between this result and the definition. Is it simply because for any subfamily,

$P(\bigcap^{\infty}_{i \in J}A_{i})=\Pi^{\infty}_{i \in J}P(A_{i})$, where $J$ is a sub-family?

Answer (score 0):

By definition $P(\cap_{n=1}^{m} A_n)=\prod_{n=1}^{m} P(A_n)$ for each $m$. Take limit as $m \to \infty$.